# Edit Link for Custom Table Record Items in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, view, edit

My Drupal module prototype/experiment adds a preorder database table.  I can add pre orders and then, after adding the necessary Views-module hooks, display a list of
 pre orders.

Now I'd like to add an edit link (or button).  I see that if the
 Views content is a node (and maybe other known tables) the Views UI
 gives an option of an edit link.  That would be perfect.

How can I use the Views module to edit records of my preorder table? 
 I'm guessing that I need to add some Views hook functions to my module
 .inc file but I can't work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've tried this already but there's a very handy module - Editable views : https://drupal.org/project/editableviews, that will let you edit fields in your view.